# How to view reforging templates based on a characters gear via ingame add-ons

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am new to SimulationCraft and I was wondering if there is anyway possible to take the results of SimulationCraft and post them to some WoW add-on that will help me with reforges. I want to get the max possible DPS for my rogue and I'm almost certain there is a way to do this; I just haven't found it. If someone can tell me what add-on is best for this and how to optimize reforges for my combat rogue, that would be great.

I've tried ReforgeLite by using the combat rogue preset. After reforging my gear with its recommendations vs what askmrrobot.com has, my DPS went down by almost 1K. I guess my question is, is there an optimal way to use the results of SimulationCraft with another tool to get max dps throughput for my class/spec?

I'm open for any suggestions on how to take the most advantage of my currently equipped gear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out the [ShadowCraft](http://shadowcraft.mmo-mumble.com/) spreadsheet, and reading through [this](http://elitistjerks.com/f78/t108630-shadowcraft_rogue_spreadsheet_4_0_a/) post if you can't figure out some specifics.  This spreadsheet is one of the best dps resources for any class out there.

Answer (score 1):

[ShadowPanther](http://shadowpanther.net/) is a very good website for helping you out with your Rogue.
also, tools such as the [Java-based optimal Rogue reforging calculator](http://elitistjerks.com/f78/t115730-java_based_optimal_rogue_reforging_calculator/) or the [Complete Rogue Reforger tool](http://elitistjerks.com/f78/t115053-complete_rogue_reforger_tool/) are good starting points.

Regarding your question:

```
is there an optimal way to use the results of SimulationCraft with 
another tool to get max dps throughput for my class/spec?
```

I do not know the tools but in the end regardless of the tools you use to pimp your stats, there is no one good formula which will be like magic.

I have tried many high DPS specs on my Rogue and sometimes have ended up with less DPS than before. That is because some rotations just don't feel right to me and as such I was not able to capitalise properly on the spec/stats.

You can have the best spec and stats and can still suck at DPS if you don't play the spec right and just don't feel right in a given playstyle.

Resources such as ShadowPanther or ElitistJerks are very good in helping you find the right spec and best stats to focus on.

Focusing on a single stat for reforging is bad as well due to diminishing returns. At some point it just doesn't make sense to add more to a specific stat but start raising some of the more secondary stats instead.

In the end getting the best DPS is about learning rotations, knowing your skills and procs as well as your CDs and a lot of practice. Timing the execution of the right skills at the right time combined with trinkets, CDs and procs = higher DPS than having a perfect spec and stats one is unable to play.

Off course, if you manage to play a setup perfectly well and have the stats which are best for the skills you use, then you are in DPS heaven :)

Answer (score 1):

[WoW Reforge](http://wowreforge.com) will allow you to enter stat weights, soft caps, required values, etc and then optimise your reforging accordingly. This is a stand alone website though, and not an in-game addon.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a website like [AskMrRobot](http://www.askmrrobot.com/) which loads your character details from the WoW armory and then calculates upgrade paths, item reforges, gemming, and enchanting for you.

Comment: Not that AskMrRobot isn't a good tool, but for the specific question, he had already mentioned that he tried it, and wanted to see if there was anything that worked better.  AskMrRobot also has some discrepancies when it comes to their interpretation of "optimization."  For a casual raider it's fine, but their algorithms aren't pristine enough for a min-maxer.

Comment: no but you can customise your own stat weights within AMR, when used in conjunction with RAWR or SimCraft to calculate your own stat weights it works quite well